# TomEE Embedded: Resource defined in resources.xml not available within webapp

Tags: datasource, jndi, apache-tomee, openejb, tomee-7

I'm currently trying to run a simple webapp on **TomEE Embedded** (TomEE Version 7.0.5).

According to the [docs](https://tomee.apache.org/advanced/tomee-embedded/index.html), I can start the TomEE and deploy the classpath as a webapp like this. I've set the document base to `src/main/webapp`.

```java
try (final Container container = new Container(new Configuration())
                                      .deployClasspathAsWebApp("", new File("src/main/webapp"))) {
    container.await();
}
```

I have defined a datasource in `WEB-INF/resources.xml` which looks like this:

```xml
<Resource id="myDataSource" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    JdbcDriver org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    JdbcUrl jdbc:hsqldb:file:hsqldb
    UserName sa
    Password
</Resource>
```

And I've setup a reference in the web.xml:

```xml
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>myDataSource</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
```

Then I try to lookup this datasource in my Servlet via JNDI.

```java
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
  try {
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/myDataSource");
    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();    
    ...
}
```

When the TomEE starts, it seems like my DataSource is created (at least there is some output about that in the logs). However when I try to lookup the DataSource in my servlet, I get an unconfigured dbcp2 connection pool as a DataSource which throws the following exception when `ds.getConnection()` is called:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2186)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2066)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1525)
    at TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:32)
    ...
```

The same configuration works fine on a standalone TomEE (I tried TomEE Webprofile) or when using the TomEE Maven Plugin. Is there anything I'm missing to get it running also for Embedded TomEE?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Tomee embedded does not bind a custom webapp classloader by default so does not have comp/ always bound. You can pass properties to the context to force it to be openejb one or use openejb:Resource/myDataSource or java:openejb/Resource/myDataSource naming.